# Find the source of waves of latency from Redis using Node.js

Tags: node.js, server, redis, latency, node-redis

I am investigating some latency issues on my server, and I've narrowed it down but not enough to solve it. I'm hoping someone with more experience with Redis or Node.js can help.

Within a function that is called a few thousand times per minute, scaling up and down with web traffic, I send a `GET` request to my redis client to check if a process is complete. I've noticed increased latency for my web requests, and it appears as though the redis `GET` command is taking up the bulk of my server time. Which surprised me, as I always thought redis was wicked fast all the time. And if I look at Redis's "time spent" info, it says everything is under 700 microseconds.

That didn't jive with what I was seeing from my transaction monitoring setup, so I added some logging to my code:

```
const start = Date.now();
client.get(`poll:${submittedId}`, (err, res) => {
    console.log(`${Date.now() - start}`);
    //other stuff
})
```

Now my logs print the number of milliseconds spend on each redis `GET`. I watch that for a while, and see a surprising pattern.

Most of the time, there are lots of `1`s and an occasional number in the 10s or sometimes 100s. Then, periodically, all the gets across the server slow down, **reaching up to several seconds for each get to complete**. Then after a while the numbers curve back down and things are running smoothly again.

**What could be causing this sort of behaviour?**

Things I've tried to investigate:

1. Like I mentioned, I've combed through redis's performance data, as presented on Heroku's redis dashboard, and it doesn't have any complaints or latency spikes.
2. I confirmed that all these requests are coming from a small number of connections, because I read that opening and closing too many can cause issues.
3. I looked into connection pooling, thinking maybe the transactions are being queued and causing a backlog, but the internet seems to say this isn't necessary for Redis and Node.

Really appreciate anyone taking the time to advise on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like Redis blocked in bgsave. Check if

1. your Redis used memory is large.
2. use lastsave command to assure the bgsave span.
3. close aof always.
4. use slowlog to assure if other command blocked.